# spring-boot-admin can't seem to change colors despite editing variables.css

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I wish to change the CSS colors in `spring-boot-admin-server-ui` and thought it would be as simple as changing the various colors in the:

`spring-boot-admin-server-ui/src/main/frontend/public/variables.css`

I then do a `mvn clean install -DskipTests` and also do the same to my app that I am using the sba starter in.

But the new colors don't show up. I have looked in other places and cannot figure out why?

Am I not building the UI correctly? Are the colors defined elsewhere?

Appreciate any help.

EDIT - adding env

SBA revision = 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT as I cloned the repo and am building from main branch

Java 17 OpenJDK

**Update -**

I look in the `target/dist/` folder and the `variables.css` does have my changes. Maybe it's just not deploying properly?
If I look at the `variables.css` in my devtools on the browser it shows the default original values.

**Update 2 -**

I seem to have got this working but not in the way I thought.

I edited the `tailwind.config.js` to hard code my color gradients:

before

```
          DEFAULT: 'var(--main-500)',
          50: withOpacity('--main-50'),
          100: withOpacity('--main-100'),
          200: withOpacity('--main-200'),
          300: withOpacity('--main-300'),
          400: withOpacity('--main-400'),
          500: withOpacity('--main-500'),
          600: withOpacity('--main-600'),
          700: withOpacity('--main-700'),
          800: withOpacity('--main-800'),
          900: withOpacity('--main-900')
```

after:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'sba': {
          DEFAULT: '#015B82',
          50: '#E6EFF2',
          100: '#E6EFF2',
          200: '#CCDEE6',
          300: '#CCDEE6',
          400: '#99BDCD',
          500: '#99BDCD',
          600: '#679DB4',
          700: '#015B82',
          800: '#014968',
          900: '#01374E'
```

If I understand it correctly, the `withOpacity('--main-xxx')` was generating color values in `variables.css` to gradients of the default color. But for some reason, this didn't seem to be working.

My solution was to eliminate the functions and just put in my gradients by hand. So this works now.

It took me a long time to figure this out and I still didn't solve why the "real" way isn't working.

Still interested in why, if anyone knows.

**Update 3 -**

I noticed in the npm build part, there is this warning:

````
vite v3.2.5 building for production...
[INFO] <script src="sba-settings.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute```

not sure if this is normal.
````

Comment: it can be cache issue, so try to hard reset cache with your browser or try with different browser to see if it's cache issue.

Comment: It's not a cache issue. I was running it with the cache off and tried it on an incognito browser as well with same results